# Confusion on Google Drive API, how can I download contents of folders? (node.js)

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, google-authentication

Hi I am trying to take the data returned to me from using the google drive api quickstart for node, and download the contents of docx files directly to my repo.

Here is my code so far, pretty much taken directly from this quickstart page, https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/nodejs

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var google = require('googleapis');
var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');

// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/drive-nodejs-quickstart.json
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'];
var TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
    process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'drive-nodejs-quickstart.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
    return;
  }
  // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the
  // Drive API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listFiles);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 *
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
  var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
  var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
  var auth = new googleAuth();
  var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
      getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
    } else {
      oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    }
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oauth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback to call with the authorized
 *     client.
 */
function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
  var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
  var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function(code) {
    rl.close();
    oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, token) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
        return;
      }
      oauth2Client.credentials = token;
      storeToken(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Store token to disk be used in later program executions.
 *
 * @param {Object} token The token to store to disk.
 */
function storeToken(token) {
  try {
    fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code != 'EEXIST') {
      throw err;
    }
  }
  fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token));
  console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
}
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/text/plain
/**
 * Lists the names and IDs of up to 10 files.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listFiles(auth) {
  var service = google.drive('v3');
  service.files.list({
    auth: auth,
    pageSize: 10,
    fields: "nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    var files = response.files;
    if (files.length == 0) {
      console.log('No files found.');
    } else {
      console.log('Files:');
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        if(file.name.includes('doc')){
   ************  download file somehow ************
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

`From reading their documentation(https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/  and https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export#http-request)`, it looks like I'm supposed to export the url with the id to whatever mimetype I need, but even in the browser this is giving me the error:
"Not found"

For instance it tells me to use this url:
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files///export

given the id:
"1QekrRHbSLu0mDZt64gTMyCOQlWgubufycK1-3249YQY"

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1QekrRHbSLu0mDZt64gTMyCOQlWgubufycK1-3249YQY/text/plain/export
```

The browser says "Not found"

if I go to the same url without /text/plain/export `(https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1QekrRHbSLu0mDZt64gTMyCOQlWgubufycK1-3249YQY/)` I get the error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

can anyone tell me how to save my file?

Comment: If you have problems for my answer, feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 1):

How about this sample script?

### Modification points :

1. When `Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded...` is shown, Drive API had been possibly used without authorization.
2. In your script, files cannot been downloaded using the scope of `var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'];`.

### Modified script :

In order to use this sample, please do as follows.

1. Replace from your `listFiles()` to my one.
2. Set `folderid`. This script can retrieve files in the folder with `folderid`.
3. Delete `drive-nodejs-quickstart.json`. I think that there is the file at `.credentials` in your home directory.
4. Change the SCOPE from `var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'];` to `var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'];`.
5. Run script, retrieve the code and authorize.

And this sample supposes as follows. So please confirm them.

1. [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/nodejs) is used and default quickstart works fine. If this doesn't work, please confirm https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/nodejs again.
2. From your file ID, it seems that you want to download Google Document. So in this script, `files.export` is used.
3. From your question, it seems that you want to convert from Google Document to text data. So in this script, the Google Document is downloaded as text data.
4. Files in the trash box are ignored.
5. Method of file search is performed by `if (e.name.includes('doc')) {` in your script.

#### Script :

```
function listFiles(auth) {
  var service = google.drive('v3');
  var folderid = "### Folder ID ###";
  service.files.list({
    auth: auth,
    q: "'" + folderid + "' in parents and trashed=false",
    fields: "files(id, name)"
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    response.files.forEach(function(e){
      if (e.name.includes('doc')) {
        var dlfile = fs.createWriteStream(e.name + ".txt");
        service.files.export({
          auth: auth,
          fileId: e.id,
          mimeType: 'text/plain'
        }).on('end', function() {
          console.log("Done.");
        }).on('error', function(err) {
          console.error(err);
          return process.exit();
        }).pipe(dlfile);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.